# Set of finite sums is dense

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $a_n \to 0$ but $\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n$ diverges. Show that the set of sums $\sum_{n \in S} a_n$, where $S$ ranges over the finite sets of positive integers, is dense, i.e. every open interval of non-negative real numbers contains a number which equals at least one of these sums.

I guess given a real $x$ one can greedily pick terms of the sequence to reach (as a sum) $x$ arbitrarily close, but no idea how to formalize this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You might find the following paper interesting:  Rafe Jones, Achievement sets of sequences, Amer. Math. Monthly 118 (2011), no. 6, 508-521.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the interval be $(x,y)$.

Let $b_i$ be the subsequence of the $a_i$ with $ a_i < y-x$.

$b_i$ excludes at most a finite number of $a_i$ and therefore its sums also diverge.

Now let $n$ be the largest value with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i \leq x$ and note that $x<\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}b_i < x + (y-x) = y$.

Comment: Why have you written $0<a_i<y-x$ ? You could write $0\leqslant a_i<y-x$. Why do you need that $0<a_i$ ? Moreover, why have you written that $b_i$ excludes at most a finite number of non-zero $a_i$ ? You could write that $b_i$ excludes at most a finite number of $a_i$. Why do you need to write “non-zero” ?